# How to Zoom Image in Android using Universal Image Loader and View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader, zooming

I have extended the image view, and passed it to Universal Image Loader. Its works fine, but sometimes out-of-memory issues occur due to some decoding image scaling problem (found in log cat).

Here is the my code:

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = ImageConstants.DEFAULT_MAX_ZOOM;
    float[] matrixScale;

    float redundantXSpace;
    float redundantYSpace;

    float width;
    float height;

    static final int CLICK = 3;
    final int measureValue = 2;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    float right;
    float bottom;
    float origWidth;
    float origHeight;
    float bmWidth;
    float bmHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        final int matrixScaleSize = 9;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        matrixScale = new float[matrixScaleSize];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                matrix.getValues(matrixScale);
                float x = matrixScale[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = matrixScale[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                        float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                        if (scaleWidth < width) {
                            deltaX = 0;
                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                            deltaY = 0;
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);
                        } else {
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);

                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }
                        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        if (bm != null) {
            bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
            bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
        }
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        // Fit to screen.
        float scale;
        float scaleX = (float) width / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) height / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        saveScale = 1f;

        // Center the image
        redundantYSpace = (float) height - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        redundantXSpace = (float) width - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) measureValue;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) measureValue;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = width - measureValue * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = height - measureValue * redundantYSpace;
        right = width * saveScale - width - (measureValue * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (measureValue * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }
            right = width * saveScale - width - (measureValue * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
            bottom = height * saveScale - height - (measureValue * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
            if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / measureValue, height / measureValue);
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    matrix.getValues(matrixScale);
                    float x = matrixScale[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float y = matrixScale[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                        if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                            if (y < -bottom)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                            else if (y > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                        } else {
                            if (x < -right)
                                matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                            else if (x > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
                matrix.getValues(matrixScale);
                float x = matrixScale[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = matrixScale[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (x < -right)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                    else if (x > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    if (y < -bottom)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                    else if (y > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                }
            }
            return true;

        }
    }
```

Please give suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: [Be sure to mention...](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#user-support) [Useful Info #4](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info)

Comment: I have found solution based on the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634088/blurred-imageview-after-zooming-while-using-universal-image-loader-in-android