# How to increase the photo quality in Android use Android-Universal-Imageloader?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

My project use Android-Universal-ImageLoader to display the image, but I know the ImageLoader will compress the image so that the image's quality is not good. I maybe need to show the high quality image by ImageLoader.I try to set this

```
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
```

but it doesn't work!
Anyone has some suggestions? thanks!

Comment: check out this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634088/blurred-imageview-after-zooming-while-using-universal-image-loader-in-android

Comment: @goonerDroid thanks,I try to use Picasso to load image solved myproblem,but in the end I decide to use fresco, It can avoid the memory gc caused UI paused I think！

Comment: i would recommend you to use Glide library for image loading!

Comment: @goonerDroid I try It Tomorrow! fresco is not stable!

Comment: Fresco is neat but its classes uses to much memory.Also Glide with volley are the libraries that Google uses in most of their apps

Comment: @goonerDroid yeah, you are right!

Comment: @goonerDroid I do an experiment, I surprised to find that in the high memory use situation, the Fresco has the better performance, memory use in around 70MB,but the Glide throw the OOM and memory use in around 120MB.And both has better performance than ImageLoader in GC caused UI suspend!